# Cloud Functions for Firebase firebase deploy error: "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'"

Tags: node.js, npm-install, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

When I run `firebase deploy` I get this error:

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-admin'
```

Here's my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

My `package.json` is:

```
  {
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here are my global node modules:

```
npm list -g --depth=0                                       
/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib
├── child_process@1.0.2
├── firebase-admin@5.3.0
├── firebase-tools@3.12.0
├── fs@0.0.2
├── npm@5.4.2
└── request@2.83.0
```

I don't have `firebase-admin` installed locally:
[image]

Running `npm install`, `npm install firebase-admin`, and `npm install --save firebase-admin` in the local `functions` directory return this error message:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I'm using npm version 5.4.2.

I changed `~5.2.1` to `^5.2.1`.

I removed `package-lock.json` but that didn't fix the problem.

I get the same error message when I do this in the project root directory and in the `functions` directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was to make a fresh directory and set up the "Hello world" tutorial from the Firebase documentation. This creates a `node_modules` directory that includes `firebase-admin`. I then swapped the new `node_modules` directory with the old directory and it worked.

The problem appears to have been that I had `firebase-admin` installed globally so `npm install` wouldn't install it locally in my `functions` directory, but `firebase deploy` can't find global Node modules, it has to have local Node modules. That's my guess.

Comment: Seems not to be the problem. Here, the `firebase-admin` is right there in node_modules and not installed globally, but the same error is reported on deploy

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -rf node_modules/

npm install
```

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

remove the node_modules folder or rename it. After that, edit your package.json file and set the packages versions to "*" to install the latest version of each one.